# How to make redis work when the prompt blinks empty?

Tags: redis

So I want to use redis as a tool to pass data between multiple scripts written in different languages.

I installed redis through my package manager on my O.S ( opensuse if it my help debugging ... ).

I ran sudo redis-server and redis-cli and I got this

```
wawa@linux-79q8:~/Desktop> sudo redis-server
[sudo] password for root: 
26824:C 08 May 01:37:37.913 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
26824:C 08 May 01:37:37.913 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=26824, just started
26824:C 08 May 01:37:37.913 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
26824:M 08 May 01:37:37.915 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
26824:M 08 May 01:37:37.915 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
wawa@linux-79q8:~/Desktop> redis-cli ping
```

There is nothing !!! the prompt just blink empty. I do not know how to debug this. I'm fairly new in redis.

Please help !

Edit : netsat give me this :

```
wawa@linux-79q8:~/Desktop> sudo netstat -antp | grep 6379
[sudo] password for root: 
tcp        7      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23836/redis-server  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44128         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 27034/redis-cli     
tcp       14      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:44128         ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43878         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 24530/redis-cli     
tcp       17      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:43878         ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp       15      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:43850         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp       17      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:43976         ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp       17      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:43886         ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp       18      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:43862         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp       18      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:43854         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43886         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 24786/redis-cli     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43976         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 26551/redis-cli     
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      23836/redis-server  
wawa@linux-79q8:~/Desktop>
```

Comment: what is the output of this command `netstat -antp | grep 6379` ?

Comment: @ruhul Check the edit up there ! I believe redis is running but for some reason , I can not interact with it

Comment: ok, try killing this process and rerun it in without sudo.

Comment: okay I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your redis server already running and listening on port `6379`.

> `tcp        7      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23836/redis-server`

Now you can kill your existing redis server and re-run the process.

Then, you could just connect to redis via *redis-cli*. And then try some get/set command.

---

```
$ redis-cli

127.0.0.1:6379> set a "asdfasdf"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get a
"asdfasdf"
```

Comment: After commanding `redis-cli` it doesn't show anything like this?`127.0.0.1:6379>   `

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: Ok, Now things get complicated. let's ignore that port and try running it another port. what about `redis-server --port 9021` ? and  then try from another terminal `redis-cli -p 9021`.

Comment: okay .... I don't understand what is going on .. I just removed and reinstall redis-package and now all of the sudden it works .... I'll use containers to better control my environment this time. I assume it might be environment related ...